# Resizing and Transposing an Array

Tags: excel, vba

In the Excel VBA debugger I am getting a

> 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error.

The line with the error is marked with a note below. I believe that the .Range(Cells(2, j + 1)) object is causing the error but I believe that my syntax is correct. So, I am unsure why this error is occurring.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()

Dim i as Integer, j As Integer, lrow As Long, rng As Range, cell As Range, size as Integer

Sheets("Std. BOMs").Select
size = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F3:F999"), "Total")
ReDim arrVal(1 To size) As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

set rng = Range("F3:F" & lrow)

For j = 0 To 1991
  j = j + 1
  ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(j,23), ActiveSheet.Cells(j,24)).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("E1:F1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  ActiveSheeet.Cells(j,25).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("G1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
     i = 0
     For Each cell In rng
         If Application.WorksheetFunction.ISNA(cell) Then
              Exit For
         ElseIF InStr(1, cell.Value, "Total", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
              i = i + 1
              arrVal(i) = cell.Offset(0,1).Value
         End If
     Next cell
   Sheets("Matrix").Range(Cells(2, j + 1)).Resize(i, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrVal)        '---------Line with 1004 Error----------'
  Next j
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
  Range("H7").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @dwirony, I believe that I only need one cell. I am trying to transpose an array to begin at (2, j +1) and write the array values of i down the  j+1 column. Would `Sheets("Matrix").Range(Cells(2, j+1), Cells(i, j+1)).Resize(i, 1).Value=Application.Transpose(arrVal)' work?

Comment: Right, you only need one cell - you are currently using `Range()` which is asking for two. My solution below is the proper syntax for using only one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing that line to

`Sheets("Matrix").Cells(2, j + 1)).Resize(i, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrVal)`

`Range()` requires 2 `Cells`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this syntax but the debugger still throws the 1004 error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is `i` definitely not zero?